# Unity keeps crashing when I click play, even though ive only written about 5 lines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's another probably stupidly simple question, but I'm starting out and really apreciate any help

I'm trying to figure out c# in unity by trying a 2d boids simulation. I've got to the FIRST step of spawning 5 boids randomly on the screen (done so by taking the camera specs and randomizing values within those bounds) and instantiating within a for loop. Problem is, Unity crashes every time I click play to check it out.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BoidSpawnScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Boid;
    public int NumberOfBoids;
    

    void SpawnBoids() {
    float cHeight = Camera.main.orthographicSize * 2f;
    float cWidth = cHeight * 2f * Camera.main.aspect;

        for (int i = 0; i<NumberOfBoids; i++ ){
            float randomY = Random.Range(-cHeight/2f, cHeight/2f);
            float randomX = Random.Range(-cWidth/2f, cWidth/2f);
            Vector2 spawnPosition = new Vector2(randomX, randomY);
            GameObject newBoid = Instantiate(Boid, spawnPosition, Random.rotation);

        }
    }




    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        SpawnBoids();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

I've written probably 5 lines here (exaggeration) I have no idea where it's going wrong. I've already gone through and tried literally anything I can think of, which isn't much, because I've never done this before.

EDIT: So in my desperation I recreated the unity project and copy and pasted the code you see above, except this time changed number of boids to 2...
[image: big bad mistake]

this leads me to think my for loop is broken but I know enough to know that it's syntaxed correctly

Comment: Does it also happen when you put `NumberOfBoids=0`? just as a sanity check

Comment: no i just tried it and it works as 0

Comment: First thought: `NumberOfBoids` is set to something fancy in inspector and your machine is running out of memory

Comment: its 5 just for test purposes, and I have a pretty solid laptop that should have absolutely no problem running this

Comment: Did you attach the script on the boid prefab too?

Comment: yea otherwise the boid spam on the update wouldnt have happened no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attached SS tells it all. (clone)... (clone)(clone)... is because you have added the same script on instantiated boids too. Each one of them instantiates more boids and it's an endless loop to me.

Comment: That's it, you've gone and done the impossible. In all seriousness, thank you for the help. I have a github clone of a more complicated 3d boid model and i couldn't understand why they used a spawner to generate them, it makes sense now.